# cs50 Pset4 filter blur function not working as expected

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, cs50

so i,ve been trying to complete the cs50 pset4 filter (less comfortable) today but no matter how many things i tried, i  just cant  seem to get the blur function right. i have tried nesting many for loops together and making copies of the 2d array image, but still check50 is not giving a single correct answer for the blur function. i am not getting any errors while compiling it or running it.
here is the code

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

//temp equals image
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        // copy equals image on every iteration so the blurred parts become non-blurred
        for (int k = 0; k < height; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < width; l++)
            {
                copy[k][l] = image[k][l];
            }
        }
        
        // just some variables for easy use
        int n = i + 1;
        int m = i - 1;
        int o = j + 1;
        int p = j - 1;

        if (n == height)
        {n -= 1;}
        else if (m < 0)
        {m = 0;}

        if (o == width)
        {o -= 1;}
        else if (p < 0)
        {p = 0;}

        // using the array copy and not image
        RGBTRIPLE center = copy[i][j];
        RGBTRIPLE top = copy[n][j];
        RGBTRIPLE bottom = copy[m][j];
        RGBTRIPLE left = copy[i][p];
        RGBTRIPLE right = copy[i][o];
        RGBTRIPLE top_left = copy[n][p];
        RGBTRIPLE bottom_left = copy[m][p];
        RGBTRIPLE top_right = copy[n][o];
        RGBTRIPLE bottom_right = copy[m][o];

        int avgred = (center.rgbtRed + top.rgbtRed + bottom.rgbtRed + left.rgbtRed + right.rgbtRed + top_left.rgbtRed + bottom_left.rgbtRed + top_right.rgbtRed + bottom_right.rgbtRed) / 9.0;
        int avggreen = (center.rgbtGreen + top.rgbtGreen + bottom.rgbtGreen + left.rgbtGreen + right.rgbtGreen + top_left.rgbtGreen + bottom_left.rgbtGreen + top_right.rgbtGreen + bottom_right.rgbtGreen) / 9.0;
        int avgblue = (center.rgbtBlue + top.rgbtBlue + bottom.rgbtBlue + left.rgbtBlue + right.rgbtBlue + top_left.rgbtBlue + bottom_left.rgbtBlue + top_right.rgbtBlue + bottom_right.rgbtBlue) / 9.0;
        
        // saving the blurred in temp on every iteration
        temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round(avgred);
        temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(avggreen);
        temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(avgblue);
    }
}

// image equals the blurred temp
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        image[i][j] = temp[i][j];
    }
}
return;
}
```

this is my best attempt yet (or so do I think), but still nothing has changed about the outcome. this really works in my head and i,ve tried tinkering with some other ways and function to apply this but still the same result.
i think that the already blurred pixels are affecting the blur of other pixels but thats why i am changing array copy back to the array image on every iteration, but doesn't seem to work.

i dont want to copy the answer from someone else on the internet so i would really like some help on where my mistakes might be.

this is the rgbt struct,

```
typedef struct
{
BYTE  rgbtBlue;
BYTE  rgbtGreen;
BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

The output i am getting is,

````
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "126 140 149\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "80 95 105\n", not "66 80 90\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel in corner
    expected "70 85 95\n", not "51 64 74\n"
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "51 64 74\n66 8..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "51 64 74\n66 8..."```

Thanks
````

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including a complete program that other people can compile and execute with no changes or additions, an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, the observed output, and the output desired instead.

Comment: well, this is actually a part of a non-executable file "headers.c" which is a part of headers.h, which itself is the part of a bigger file "filter.c", that has all the input and that i cannot recreate as a beginner.

Comment: i can give the struct of RGBTRIPLE, and the output i am getting

Comment: the reality is that the width is padded so the actual width (in pixels) is a multiple of 4. Your posted code does not seem to be allowing for that padding

Comment: the posted code is using `9` for a divisor when calculating the blur value but there is only 8 surrounding pixels that are being used in the calculation